# Ambiguous use of 'dispatch_get_main_queue()' - XMPP

Tags: swift, chat, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am doing a project with chat activity using XMPP.I am using the following code to generate it,

```
 var stream:XMPPStream!

 let xmppRosterStorage = XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage()
 var xmppRoster: XMPPRoster!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    xmppRoster = XMPPRoster(rosterStorage: xmppRosterStorage)

    stream = XMPPStream()
    stream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

    xmppRoster.activate(stream)

    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.setTitle("SendMessage", for: .normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 90, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40)//CGRect(90, 100, 300, 40)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sendMessage), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(button)
    stream.myJID = XMPPJID(string: "test@localhost")

    do {
       try stream.connect(withTimeout: 30)
    }
    catch {
       print("error occured in connecting")
    }

    }
```

I refer [this](http://shubhank101.github.io/iOSAndroidChaosOverFlow/2016/08/Chat-Application-Using-XMPP-Swift-Tutorial) tutorial.
 but I am getting some issue in the following line

```
stream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
```

the issue is,

> Ambiguous use of 'dispatch_get_main_queue()'

The main thing is I am using **Swift4.2**

Anyone please help me to find out the solution. Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new syntax is `DispatchQueue.main`, or just `.main` if the context requires a `DispatchQueue`. Thus:

```
stream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: .main)
```

Comment: I already tried that , but it didn't call the delegate methods

Comment: Okay, but that's not what you complained about your post. If you have a different problem than a compile-time error, you need to post the details of your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below syntax:

```
stream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: .main)
```

But in xmpp, you should need to update the delegate method in swift4 syntax. they provide only swift 3 format.

after changing the latest xmpp delegate methods everything working fine for me...